# Shopware 6 - custom fields from Category in iteration of Products

Tags: shopware6

New to Shopware 6 and looking for a way to extend the `Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductEntity` on the fly with custom fields added to categories.

- I have an iteration of products
- I can access the categoryTree with the categoryIds
- I need the data from the category (especially custom fields) for prosessing
- Looking for a method like getCategoryDataByID() including the custom fields added to that category

```php
// Products from Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\SalesChannelProductEntity
foreach ($products as $product) {
   // The $product->categoryTree returns an array with the Category Ids.
   $productCategories = $product->categoryTree;

   // Get the category data with ...
   ...

}
```

I've been loking for a method or way to get data for given ids.

Answer (score 1):

The `ProductDefinition` has an association `categoriesRo` which includes all assigned categories as well as their collective predecessors. The corresponding getter of the entity `getCategoriesRo` will return `null` by default unless the entities have been fetched with the added association:

```php
$criteria->addAssociation('categoriesRo');
```

Depending on where you're intercepting the collection of `SalesChannelProductEntity`, you might have to alter the criteria before they're fetched.

```php
class ProductListingSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['handleCriteria', -100],
            ],
            ProductSuggestCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['handleCriteria', -100],
            ],
            ProductSearchCriteriaEvent::class => [
                ['handleCriteria', -100],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function handleCriteria(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
        $criteria->addAssociation('categoriesRo');
    }
}
```

Be mindful of the potential repercussions on the performance when fetching lots of category data with the products.

Comment: Thank you dneustadt.
I've spent some time with this now and do not get this to work.
I'm switching to the store-api and try to get the information needed this way.